# Different (Non-Equivalent) Derivatives for the Same Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x) = \left[x^2(3-x)\right]^\frac{1}{3}$

1. $f(x) = x^\frac{2}{3}(3-x)^\frac{1}{3} \\
   \implies f'(x) = \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}(3-x)^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{1}{3}x^\frac{2}{3}(3-x)^{-\frac{2}{3}} $

This is essentially using the quotient-rule (and a little bit of chain-rule).

2. $f(x) = (3x^2 - x^3)^\frac{1}{3} \\ 
   \implies f'(x) = (3x^2 - x^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(2x-x^2)$

This was essentially using the chain-rule.

Even if I expand out the brackets, and simplify, I am not able to get one into the form of the other. They seem, apparently, to be different answers altogether!

Have I made a serious blunder somewhere?

Comment: In 1. the exponent on $(3-x)$ should be positive one-third, not negative.

Comment: Actually that was a typo in my post. The question still stands.

Comment: Both forms of the answer simplify to $\dfrac{2-x}{\sqrt[3]{x(3-x)^2}}$.

Comment: I was, in fact, repeatedly making a sign error. Ah! I am sorry for wasting your time with this.

Comment: My time was not wasted. I am a retired teacher and cannot break the habit of helping students. Peace!